# Git - update files in multiple projects and push to separate repo?

Tags: git, docker, gitlab

I have the following setup:

```
Projects/
    projA/
        .git/
        .gitlab-ci.yml
        src/
    projB/
        .git/
        .gitlab-ci.yml
        src/
    projC/
        .git/
        .gitlab-ci.yml
        src/
```

where each projX is its own project and has a corresponding Git repo. The projects have their own CI/CD file, but the Docker image used in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` files is the same across all of the projects.

My question is, is there an efficient/easy way to update all of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` files in every local repo and push the changes to every remote Git repo?

I'm aware that I could write a shell script that would do this for me, but I'm wondering if anyone knows if git provides such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file should always be the same across the three repos, maintaining three copies of it is probably the wrong way to go. At best, it's error-prone, and at worst it will lead to conflicts where they get out of sync and you aren't sure which is the right one.

A different approach could be to put this file in its own repository and have all three projects hold it as a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Make sure you define `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive` for it, though, so the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is always updated before the CI is run.
For additional details, see [GitLab's Using Git submodules with GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html) documentation.

Comment: I recommend *not* doing this. The end state is a bespoke build system that will slow changes down a lot. Copying stuff is cheap and reliable. Abstractions come at a cost.

Comment: @DanielB It all boils down to the numbers, I guess. If it takes a couple of seconds to update a submodule and your entire pipeline takes ten minutes to run, it's negligible. If the entire pipeline runs in under a minute I agree this is bad idea.